# Laravel jquery sortable is not serialising data

Tags: jquery, laravel-4, eloquent, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi I am trying to use jquery sortable and laravel to order some tasks in my database however when I try to serialise the data it seems like it is lost, as when I console log the variable I assign it to it is blank.

e.g.

```
var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
console.log(data);
```

I have also tried the following and it comes back undefined in the console

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-task-id");
console.log(id);
```

My full jQuery is as follows:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
        cursor: 'move',
        axis: 'y',
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var id = $(this).attr("data-task-id");
            console.log(id);
            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            console.log(data);
            // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/backlog/sort/update'
            })
        }
});
```

and my controller is as follows:

```
public function updateBacklogOrder() {
    $updateRecordsArray = Input::all();

    $i = 1;

    // Loop though the <li>
    foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $recordID) {

        BacklogTask::where('id', $id)->update(array('order' => Input::get('order')));
        $i++;
    }

    return Response::json('ok');  
}
```

My blade file is as follows:

@foreach($tasks as $task)
            id}}">{{$task->name}}
        @endforeach

This renders the following:

Task One
     Task Two
     Task Three
     Task Four

Its strange that the data is not being serialized using the sortable method, if I move it outside it complains that I've loaded this outside of the sortable method. Any ideas what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Run console.log(this). What does it return?

Comment: @Jyeon the ordered list is output into the console

Comment: Can you include your markup in your question?

Comment: @Jyeon have updated with the html

Comment: It doesn't look like your wrapping them in any kind of element. You need to wrap all the elements in a <ul> and the each individual task in an <li> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `id` attributes to use `serialize`. If you have only `data` attributes it won't work. Structure should be like this:

```
<li id="key_value"></li>
```

That'll output a string like this:

```
key[]=value&key[]=value// etc.
```

You can customize a bit more by setting your wanted key, like this:

```
$(this).sortable('serialize', {key: "sort"})
```

This will output:

```
sort=value&sort-value// etc.
```

But you need `id` attribute, and it must be properly formatted (default is underscore between key and value, but you can use "=" and "-" also. In your case, you can add ids dynamically on update, but it would be more efficient setting them in the `HTML` directly. 
But this should give an output:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
        cursor: 'move',
        axis: 'y',
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var id = $(this).attr("data-task-id");
            $(this).find('[data-task-id]').each(function () {
                 $(this).attr('id', 'task-' + $(this).data('task-id'));
            });
            console.log(id);
            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize', {key:"task-id");
            console.log(data);
            // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/backlog/sort/update'
            })
        }
});
```

EDIT:

The order of the parameters will be in the order they are in the sortable. Like this:

```
task-id=value_of_first&task-id=value_of_second //etc.
```

SECOND EDIT:

Turns out there's a way to use other attributes in serialize, but you need to set different options. This should work without assigning an id:

```
var data = $(this).sortable('serialize', {key:'task-id',attribute: 'data-task-id', expression: /(\w+)/});
```

To clarify a bit further, if you take both parts, you'll see you can get `post` pretty much the string you want according to your needs. At this point, from what I understand from your controller, maybe serialize isn't necessarily the best way to go, but since you already have your setup, you could send parameters in the form `id=order` this way:

```
    $(this).find('[data-task-id]').each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr('data-to-send', $(this).data('task-id')+'_'+i);
    });
    $(this).sortable('serialize',{attribute: 'data-to-send'}).replace(/\[\]/g, '');
```

Comment: ahh cool thats sending the id through but how can I send the order value too?